# Sublime Text multiline comment with partial selection

Tags: sublimetext

Could I make multiline comment for partially selected lines with default Sublime Text adjusments?

Select the text this way:
[image]
And press `Ctrl+/` to comment from the beginning of the block to its end.

Comment: Do you want to comment the complete first and last line or only the selected parts? Commenting only the selected parts should be standard behavior.

Comment: Comment before <div> and after </button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found a kind of workaround.
It was inspired by the file Default.sublime-mousemap. There is an action which uses Right mouse key as modifier and expands the selection to the line boundaries:

```
{
  "button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["button2"],
  "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "line"},
  "press_command": "drag_select"
}
```

So the steps to perform the full line comment on partial selection:

1. Create a macro and save as `comment-add.sublime-macro` to the `Packages\User`:

   ```
   [
     {
       "args": 
       {
         "to": "line"
       },
       "command": "expand_selection", 
     },
     {
       "args":
       {
         "by": "characters",
         "extend": true,
         "forward": false
       },
       "command": "move"
     },
     {
       "args":
       {
         "block": false
       },
       "command": "toggle_comment"
     }
   ]
   ```
2. Add custom keyboard shortcut:

   ```
   {
       "keys": ["ctrl+shift+2"], 
       "command": "run_macro_file", 
       "args": {"file": "Packages/User/comment-add.sublime-macro"}
   },
   ```
3. Select blocks with partial lines and use the shortcut to comments whole blocks.